# LuaLaTeX: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} messes up siunitx's mu letter and shows ţ

Tags: luatex, font-encodings

I have a document containing a lot of TikZ images with pgfplots (See MWE below). Because some of these plots deal with a lot of data, I had to switch from `pdflatex` to `lualatex`.

I use the `siunitx` package for units like micro-meters etc. I discovered, that everything works when using `pdflatex`:
[image: pdflatex]

However, compiled with `lualatex` I get these Ts with the little tail below them (ţ) instead of a greek mu.

[image: lualatex]

If I remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` The error is gone and both `pdflatex` and `lualatex` work. Is there a way to get this working with `lualatex`?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
        width=7cm,
        height=7cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=100, xtick={0,10,...,100},
        ymin=1, ymax=8, ytick={0,1,...,8},
        xlabel={Stuff},
        ylabel={Stuff},
        grid,
        ]
        \draw[thick,->, >=latex'] (axis cs: 50,6) -- (axis cs: 40, 1.5) node[pos=0, above, align=center, fill=white]{Stuff \SIrange{7}{15}{\micro\meter}\\in \SI{1}{\micro\meter} steps};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: never use either of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already suspected something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace both `inputenc` and `fontenc` by `fontspec` for correct encoding in lualatex : `\usepackage{fontspec}` **or** `\usepackage{unicode-math}` :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
        width=7cm,
        height=7cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=100, xtick={0,10,...,100},
        ymin=1, ymax=8, ytick={0,1,...,8},
        xlabel={Stuff},
        ylabel={Stuff},
        grid,
        ]
        \draw[thick,->, >=latex'] (axis cs: 50,6) -- (axis cs: 40, 1.5) node[pos=0, above, align=center, fill=white]{Stuff \SIrange{7}{15}{\micro\meter}\\in \SI{1}{\micro\meter} steps};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```